# How do I get a CardScan 60 II working with SANE?

Tags: 10.10, usb, card-reader, sane

I have a **CardScan 60 II** device and installed [SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/) in my Ubuntu 10.10 laptop.

The problem is I can't make `scanimage` find the device.

Quote:

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x08f0 [Corex Technologies Corporation], product=0x1000 [Corex CardScan 60], chip=LM9832/3) at libusb:006:002
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

But I can't find the device:

```
$ sudo scanimage -L

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Comment: How did you compile sane? Sane is available in the repositories, you shouldn't have compiled it (you should have packaged it) I just want to confirm what you've done.

Comment: I downloaded the sources and run `./configure && make && sudo make isntall`... I'll try to install the package from repositories.

Comment: You will have to find the version of sane you compiled and installed and remove it. I think you may have two different versions of sane installed as sane is installed by default (as well as the cardscan driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the sane cardscan software, it doesn't appear as if the CardScan 60 II is supported. Only the CardScan 600c and 800c devices have support from this sane driver.

It's possible to force the cardscan driver to attempt to work with your device by adding the usb ids to the `cardscan.conf` file and making sure the same ids are added to a udev rule similar to those found in `40-libsane.rules`. But all of this work might just show that the device doesn't work anyway.

You need to get in touch with the cardScan manufacturers and ask them to release drivers if possible and documentation if not. We need to know how these devices work and what the protocols are. Otherwise it's going to be expensive to recreate the drivers from scratch.

Comment: As the output from find scanner says, your scanner may or may not be supported. If you're up for it. Grab the windows driver, monitor the usb using a sniffer and confirm the protocol with the source code for sane-cardscan. You might be able to fix the issue and create a patch to add support for it.

Comment: I just added the vendor and product IDs cardscan.conf but nothing changes

Comment: Then it doesn't work, I'm sorry.